# DotNetBrowser set value of form

Tags: c#, dotnetbrowser

I'm trying to set value of form in DotNetBrowser, but to get this form I have to use

`var b = browserView.Browser.GetDocument().GetElementsByTagName("span")[1];`

because ID's of forms aren't unique. The problem is that returns me

`DotNetBrowser.DOM.DOMNode`

and to make a usage from example that provides DotNetBrowser [link](https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000110038-setting-input-field-value-working-with-form). I need

`DotNetBrowser.DOM.DOMInputElement`

which I have no idea how to convert into.

Comment: a `span` isn't an `input` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `span` DOM node can be safely casted to `DOMElement`:

```
var b = browserView1.Browser.GetDocument().GetElementsByTagName("span")[1] as DOMElement;
```

You can also use a `DOMNode.NodeType` property to check the node type and then perform a safe cast:

```
if (b.NodeType == DOMNodeType.ElementNode) {
    DOMElement element = b as DOMElement;
    //...
}
```